# New build not powering up

Tags: power-supply, power

So, I ordered a bunch of parts and put them together. They should all be compatible.

My power supply unit is not faulty. It works fine when I plug it into my other system. It does not work in my new system. The PSU from my old system does not work in my new system either.

Everything is connected correctly. POWER SW, RESET SW, 24 Pin, 8 Pin. I've checked, double checked, triple checked, and repeated that process roughly 20 times.

The only other thing I can think of is that it may be due to my motherboard not being fully secured to the case. The case gave me a diagram for ATX boards and MATX boards (My board is a micro atx), so I put standoffs in all the MATX holes. However, two of them to the far right did not have a matching screw hole on the motherboard, so I removed them from the case and left the holes empty.

Other than that, I'm completely clueless.

**EDIT:**
PARTS:
i3-2100
ASRock MB-Z68MU3 LGA1155 MATX Motherboard
G.SKILL Ripjaws Series 8GB (2 x 4GB) 240-Pin DDR3 1333MHz DIMM

Some pictures:
[image: On the right of the P LED is the POWER SW]
[image: 8 Pin]
[image: 24 Pin]

Comment: What parts are you using? We can't do much if we don't know what parts these are

Comment: Also needs more details as to what you mean by "not powering up" -- is the power supply not turning on, are you getting no video, etc?

Comment: Power supply is not turning on. No fans spin, nothing lights up, no interesting sounds. Nothing.

Comment: You may have missed the connection that goes from the ON switch to your motherboard.

Comment: @SimonSheehan Are you referring to the POWER SW? Got that.

Comment: Your question still does not provide us enough information to help. Can we maybe get some good pictures from a few angles of the connections?

Comment: @SimonSheehan Added smoe pictures. Hope they help.

Comment: how about the 4 pin connector for the processor?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You're oldschool :P These days we use those 8 pins such as the one pictured above.

Comment: Sadly, i haven't built a system since 07, and i'm unlikely to for a while. Could the motherboard be a dud?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek That's crossed my mind on several occasions today. I'm not sure how I would go about testing that, though.

Comment: Did you try manually shorting (e.g. with screwdriver or pliers) the two POWER SW pins on the motherboard, in order to power up the system, i.e. bypassing the case switch? Perhaps the case's POWER SW connector, wiring, or switch is faulty.

Comment: test everything else you can separately, ram comes to mind as a relatively easy one.

Comment: Here's a link to the MB diagram: ftp://174.142.97.10/manual/Z68MUSB3.pdf

Comment: The power btn is on page 28 and the twisted red and white cables in your photo. How about adding a LED to the unconnected power LED pins to see if anything there. Not securing mounting screws is totally fine. Having bad memory should minimally get a beep. Do you have anything connected to the audio out/speakers? (diag beeps should be from MB component).

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea No, I haven't tried that. Can you give better instructions?

Comment: @jdh It will get no sound. The PSU doesn't even power up.

Comment: To short out the power switch, refer to the jumpers on page 28. Where your red/white wire pair is (in front of "- pled") - remove that block and use a flat screwdriver to momentarily short those two pins. It won't cause a problem if you miss, as a 2nd ground and the rest pins are surrouning them.

Comment: @jdh and it won't shock me or anything? EDIT: Just tried it. Got nothing. Dead MOBO I guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. An extra standoff was shorting out the motherboard. I've removed it and it all works perfectly. Thanks, guys.

Comment: That's interesting. How did you finally detect it? Was it sparking or something visual?

Comment: @jdh, while I was reading around about what the problem might be online, I saw it was a fairly common problem. So, I removed the other side plate of my build, counted the standoffs and then counted the screws in the motherboard. Saw there was an extra, so I popped off the motherboard and pulled it out. Put it all back together and booted it up fine.